# null @Resource in method triggered on event

Tags: java, ejb

I have singleton bean in which I inject resource with @Resource annotation. When I try to retrieve that resource in the method called on event, the resource is null. What's going and why resource is not injected? What solution can be found for this? I can't refuse from using observers.

```
@Singleton
@javax.ejb.Startup
@Stateless
public class ScheduleManager implements IScheduleManager
{   

    @Resource
    private TimerService timerService;

    @Override
    @Observer(value=EventConstants.SCHEDULE_CHANGE_EVENT)
    public void reSchedule(PtSchedulesDTO schedule)
    {
         Collection<Timer> timers = timerService.getTimers();
         //...
    }

    //...
}
```

Comment: `@Singleton` and `@Stateless` annotations in one class?

Comment: @Geinmachi, Yes, I've already found out why I can't use `@Singleton` and `@Stateless` togehter :) Now I use only `@Stateless` annotation, the bean is created and initialized for every call, so it works fine. But it's still interesting why resource is not injected in `@Singleton` bean when it's called on event, all tutorials use singleton

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what framework or technology you are using but for annotation (@Resource) to work, usually something must be declared to look for that annotation. It could be declared in an xml file, where it gets pick up by the framework. Also you could also check if you have a TimerService class that you need to annotate or create a bean for the framework to be able to inject it in.